# ¿Cómo puedo corregir el error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer"?

Tags: c++

Dado este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio2.h>
using namespace std;

int al_cuadrado(int);
int al_cubo(int);

int selTab(int PrimerNum, int Lineas, int Incremento)
{
    return Lineas * Incremento + PrimerNum;
}
int main()
{
    int PrimerNum = 6, Lineas = 5, Incremento = 2;

    cout << "numero  cuadrado    cubo" << endl;
    cout << "------  --------    ----" << endl;

    for (int n = PrimerNum; n < selTab; n = n + Incremento) {
        cout << setw(3) << n << "      " << setw(3) << al_cuadrado(n) << "      " << setw(4) << al_cubo(n) << endl;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int al_cuadrado(int n)
{
    return n * n;
}

int al_cubo(int n)
{
    return n * n * n;
}
```

Me marca el siguiente error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al prototipo de la función `selTab`, ésta toma tres argumentos, todos de tipo `int`, luego debes realizar la comparación del siguiente modo:

```
n < selTab(PrimerNum, Lineas, Incremento)
```

Otras cosas a tener en cuenta:

1. La librería `<conio2.h>` no es parte del estandar de C++, por lo que deberías evitar su uso.
2. Aunque válido, en el lenguaje C++ no es común nombrar a las variables utilizando el estilo `PascalCase`. Es mejor que utilices o el estilo `camelCase` o `guiones_bajos`. Así, por ejemplo los parametros de la función `selTab` podrían escribirse como `int primer_num, int lineas, int incremento`.
3. Los nombres de las funciones y procedimientos deben ser verbos que expresen lo que hace dicha función/procedimiento. En tu caso, en lugar de `al_cuadrado` / `al_cubo`, sería mejor que las nombres como `elevar_potencia_cuadrada` / `elevar_potencia_cubica`.

Answer (score 1):

> Me marca el siguiente error:
>
> > error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Que viene a decir: "*El [ISO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizaci%C3%B3n_Internacional_de_Normalizaci%C3%B3n) de C++ prohíbe la comparación entre puntero y entero*".

El error indica que el estándar de C++ prohíbe comparar un entero con un puntero (excepto `0`), lo cuál tiene sentido ya que un puntero no tiene el mismo significado semántico que un entero; como analogía podemos pensar que los punteros son códigos postales:

[image]

No tiene sentido comparar números con CP pues aunque también sean números, los CP no representan un orden si no un espacio físico, y que tengan un número mayor o menor no es indicativo de orden: en el mapa 39011 está "antes" que 39010 y éste "antes" que 39009. Así que puedes decir que 500 es menor que 39011, pero no puedes decir que 500 es menor que el CP 39011 porque no estás comparando cosas iguales.

#### El error.

El único punto de tu código en que haces una comparación es aquí:

```
for (int n=PrimerNum; n<selTab; n=n+Incremento)
//                    ~~~~~~~~ <--- comparación: ¿es 'n' menor que 'selTab'?
```

Los tipos de datos de `n` y `selTab` son `int` e `int(*)(int, int, int)` respectivamente. Es decir:

- `n` es una variable de tipo "entero".
- `selTab` es una variable de tipo "puntero a función que devuelve un entero y recibe tres enteros".

Y ahí tienes el motivo por el que tu compilador se queja, no puedes comparar un entero con un puntero (puntero a función).

Posiblemente querías escribir lo siguiente:

```
for (int n=PrimerNum; n<selTab(PrimerNum,Lineas,Incremento); n=n+Incremento)
```